# can't convert Symbol into Integer in rails 3.2.19

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

#### ParticipantsController

```
def save_bmi_measurement

  return error_response(INVALID_REQUEST, "required parameters are missing") unless params[:access_code].present? && params[:auth_token].present? && params[:weight].present? && params[:w_unit].present? && params[:h_unit].present? && params[:bmi].present?  

  @participantBmiLog = ParticipantBmiLog.new(:weight => params[:weight], :w_unit => params[:w_unit],:h_unit=>:params[:h_unit],:height=>params[:height],:bmi=>params[:bmi],:measured_date=>params[:measured_date])

  #...
```

#### participant.rb

```
has_many :bmi_logs,:class_name => "ParticipantBMILog", :dependent => :destroy
```

#### ParticipantBmiLog

```
belongs_to :participant

belongs_to :research_info  

attr_accessible :weight,:w_unit,:h_unit,:height,:bmi,:measured_date,:participant_id,:research_info_id
```

---

I am getting `can't convert Symbol into Integer` in rails 3.2.19. Please help me out.

Comment: See this you are writing this as Symbol `:h_unit=>:params[:h_unit]` it should be `:h_unit=>params[:h_unit]`

Comment: @Sontya - you should put that comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

See this you are writing params as Symbol

```
:h_unit=>:params[:h_unit]
```

it should be

```
:h_unit=>params[:h_unit]
```